# Hibernate Query Field Alias

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a complicated custom field framework I've built for my application, and I'm trying to generify things in order to help with maintenance and overhead. I've started extensive use of generics, but I've hit a bit of a snag when it comes to querying for data. I'd like to have an "alias" for fields that all have different names so that a single universal query can be used with a generic method in order to get the same general results.

To try and clarify. I have custom field values for several different parent entity models. These various custom field values each have their own class, but they all share the same basic implementation - There is an EmbeddedId composite Id that references the parent entity. This parent entity is different for each type, but they all have one. Here are two examples:

```
@Entity
public class CustomFieldEntity1Value implements Serializable, CustomFieldValueCommon {

    /***************************************************************
     * Fields
     ***************************************************************/
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private CustomFieldEntity1ValueId pk = new CustomFieldEntity1ValueId();

    @Column(name = "VALUE", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 4000)
    private String value;
}

@Embeddable
public class CustomFieldEntity1ValueId implements Serializable {

    /***************************************************************
     * Constructors
     ***************************************************************/
    
    public CustomFieldEntity1ValueId (Entity1 entity1, CustomFieldEntity1Meta customFieldMeta) {
        this.entity1 = entity1;
        this.customFieldMeta = customFieldMeta;
    }
    
    /***************************************************************
     * Fields
     ***************************************************************/

    /**
     * The parent entity that this value is directly associated with.
     */
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_ENTITY1")
    private Entity1 entity1;
    
    /**
     * The parent custom field meta that this value is directly associated with.
     */
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_CUSTOMFIELDMETA")
    private CustomFieldEntity1Meta customFieldMeta;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class CustomFieldEntity2Value implements Serializable, CustomFieldValueCommon {

    /***************************************************************
     * Fields
     ***************************************************************/
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private CustomFieldEntity2ValueId pk = new CustomFieldEntity2ValueId();

    @Column(name = "VALUE", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 4000)
    private String value;
}

@Embeddable
public class CustomFieldEntity2ValueId implements Serializable {

    /***************************************************************
     * Constructors
     ***************************************************************/
    
    public CustomFieldEntity2ValueId (Entity2 entity2, CustomFieldEntity2Meta customFieldMeta) {
        this.entity2 = entity2;
        this.customFieldMeta = customFieldMeta;
    }
    
    /***************************************************************
     * Fields
     ***************************************************************/

    /**
     * The parent entity that this value is directly associated with.
     */
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_ENTITY2")
    private Entity2 entity2;
    
    /**
     * The parent custom field meta that this value is directly associated with.
     */
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_CUSTOMFIELDMETA")
    private CustomFieldEntity2Meta customFieldMeta;
}
```

A lot is obviously omitted, but that should show my general setup. I currently have about 10 of these, and more get added which is why I'm working to generify things.

Now, what I normally do in order to get all of the values for a particular entity is reference it directly in my criteria via the proper path. I am using Hibernate.

```
CriteriaQuery<CustomFieldEntity1Value> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(CustomFieldEntity1Value.class);
Root<CustomFieldEntity1Value> root = criteriaQuery.from(CustomFieldEntity1Value.class);
criteriaQuery
    .select(root)
    .where(
        criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("pk").get("entity1").get("id"), entity1Id)
    );
```

So what I'd like to do is be able to generically reference this parent entity id in the query via an alias, so that the same code snippet can be used for all existing custom fields, and used again for any new instances I may create in the future. Something like this:

```
public <T extends CustomFieldValueCommon> List<T> getCustomFieldValues(Integer parentEntityId, Class<T> customFieldValueClass) {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(customFieldValueClass);
    Root<T> root = criteriaQuery.from(customFieldValueClass);
    criteriaQuery
        .select(root)
        .where(
            criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("parentEntityId"), parentEntityId)
        );
        
    return entityManager().createQuery(createQuery).getResultList();
}
```

It's the "parentEntityId" portion that is giving me trouble. I'd prefer not to change my composite ID classes, as that will entail possibly days of changing everything from Entity1, Entity2, etc to "Entity1 parentEntity", "Entity2 parentEntity", etc. and all corresponding references throughout the rest of the code. I'm just wondering if there is an annotation available in Hibernate or something else that Hibernate can utilize which can be used as a general alias to a field of any depth. Depending on the class, "parentEntityId" will refer to "pk.entity1.id" or "pk.entity2.id", etc. Is there any way to achieve this?